# Swift NSPredicate init.block() bindings example

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

The NSPredicate init with block is defined as so:

```
init(block: @escaping (Any?, [String : Any]?) -> Bool)
```

But I am unable to comprehend the use of the binding parameter, presented in that signature as an optional dictionary: `[String : Any]?`.

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate/1416182-init), hasn't helped much.

Can I get an example on how to use the bindings parameter in a predicate, for a CoreData search for example?

Comment: Note: "In macOS 10.6 and later, Core Data supports block-based predicates in the in-memory and atomic stores, but not in the SQLite-based store."

Comment: See [Creating Predicates Using Predicate Templates](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-219639-BCIIHDCH). Do you want to use substitution variables?

Comment: @Willeke I see, I just ran my code and yes, seems like it does not like block predicates at the sqlite level.

Comment: @Willeke I'll have a look at that link when I get a chance.

Comment: As far as I can see, the link is not related in any way to block predicates.

Comment: I used block predicates a number of times, and every time the bindings dictionary was nil.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example (does not make sense, just for demonstration):

```
let string = "abc"
let templatePredicate = NSPredicate(block: { (object, bindings) in
  return true
})
let ok = templatePredicate.evaluate(with: string, substitutionVariables: ["key": "value"])
```

If you execute this code unter Xcode, and set a breakpoint at the `return true` statement in the predicate block, you get the following:

```
Printing description of object:
▿ Optional<Any>
  - some : abc  

Printing description of bindings:
▿ Optional<Dictionary<String, Any>>
  ▿ some : 1 element
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      - key : "key"
      - value : "value"
```

Obviously, the idea is that `templatePredicate` is a re-usable predicate that can be adopted to various situations by specifying a concrete substitution variable dictionary when the predicate is evaluated. These substitution variables can then be used in the block as required.